# Library file not found in android app

Tags: android

I have developed an android app. Now when I am trying to launch it and run it on my device the following error is displayed:

[2014-11-06 14:56:01 - library] Could not find library.apk!

What should I do to avoid it and successfully run my application?

Comment: what is your project name? this library is a depenedency project?

Comment: Project's name is CharTechnician. Yes library is dependency project. The main problem is my application is unable to launch and what should I do to run it successfully.

Comment: **Project Property**--> **Java Build Path**--> **order and export** check out if you have checked that library or not (assuming you have added it in build path).

Comment: I checked it, still the same result. The application is not getting launched on my device.